# Recovering my encrypted home folder

Tags: data-recovery, directory, home-directory

Here is my situation.
I completely broke my Ubuntu on my main drive, and it just boots into a black screen and doesn't work, it is dead.

I need to recover my encrypted home folder with a live USB. I have the 32 character mount password it gives you it is first setup, but I can't seem to recover it properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the procedure described here? http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Keep getting this. find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/kernel/debug’.

Comment: Try here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/699056/how-can-i-access-my-encrypted-hard-drive-on-another-pc