# I can't login to Ubuntu 20.04 - encrypted /home partition - SOLVED

Tags: mount, login, encryption, ecryptfs

I had Ubuntu 18 before and I reinstalled Ubunto 20.04 on `/` partition. I didn't change `/home` partition during the installation process. I set the same username and. password I had before.

When I try to login to Ubuntu I choose my account, type a password. I see a black screen and I see the log in page again without any error message or something. I googled it and it looks like "login loop error".

On the login screen, I switched to the console mode (`[Alt] + [Ctrl] + [F3]`) and successfully logged in.

I executed `ls -la` in my home directory and I see only few items:

```
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/encryptfs-mount-provate.desktop
.encryptfs -> /home/.encryptfs/szymon/.encryptfs
.Private -> /home/.encryptfs/szymon/.Private
README.txt -> /usr/share/encryptfs-utils/mount-private.txt
```

I think the problem here is the lack of mounted encrypted `/home` partition. Is that a correct statement?

How to fix that?

Comment: Did you encrypt /home during install of 18.04 or after install?

Comment: I don't remember but during installation (I think)

Comment: Think that might be the problem.  20.04 was not made aware of encrypted partition.  20.04 was new install, not upgraded?  This is as far as I can help.  Will need better people to help from now.

Comment: This link might give some help, but be careful.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/699056/how-can-i-access-my-encrypted-hard-drive-on-another-pc

Comment: Yes, 20.04 was a new install

Comment: Link above is for reading an old encrypted drive/partition from another installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the issue :)

I've logged in to the system in a console hidden behind `[Ctrl] + [Alt] + [F3]`. Next I updated system and installed `cryptsetup` and `ecryptfs-mount-private`.

Next, I ran `ecryptfs-mount-private` command, provided a password to the encrypted `/home` partition and that's all.

After rebooting the partition was already mounted.

Comment: Actually you just need to have package `ecryptfs-utils` installed and everything else will just work automatically. I don't know why the Ubuntu upgrade process is not smart enough to automatically install this package if your system contains an encrypted home directory using `ecryptfs`. I think this worked automatically during Ubuntu 16.04 -> 18.04 upgrade but it failed to work with Ubuntu 18.04 -> Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade...