# ubuntu 18.04 login password changed encrypted home inaccessible

Tags: 18.04, login, password, encryption

was trying to access data on an old laptop ubuntu 18.04 that had an eCryptFS Encrypted hard drive
i could remember the encryption key but not the user password

i booted into recovery and changed the password, it seems this was a terrible mistake

Now i can no longer access the encrypted home menu

Is there any way to access this without the old user password

I thought i could remember the passsword as i used the laptop for years but dont know even if i could can i still use it to access the home folder

or would i need to change it back and reboot etc obviously a lot longer to try multiple passwords that way.

alternatively is there any way to recover the old password

Comment: Depending on how the home directory was encrypted, you should be able to mount it (either on the same machine or any other) again. Take a look at [some of the solutions for a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699056/how-can-i-access-my-encrypted-hard-drive-on-another-pc) a few years back. Hopefully that'll point you in the right direction 

Comment: pretty sure mine is like the last example eCryptFS. encrypted and im sunk without the old password